# How to integrated Keycloak and OrangeHRM (Opoen-source version)

Tags: oauth-2.0, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid-connect, orangehrm

I'm a new bee here and I would like to is ther any possible way of integrating Keycloak IDP with ORangeHRM open source version? I have tried some work mentioned on the internet but it still doesn't work.

My Orange HRM version 4.7 and Keycloak is 18.0.2.

Hope any one can help on this.

Thanks.

I have tried some work mentioned on the internet but it still doesn't work.

My Orange HRM version 4.7 and Keycloak is 18.0.2.